# cryptojs library not loading

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptojs

I want to use cryptoJS library in my angular application. I am using node and installing all the dependencies by a package.json file

i gave in my dependency in package.json as

```
  "dependencies": {
"babel-plugin-transform-es2015-for-of": "^6.6.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-systemjs": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
"crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
"lodash": "^4.17.4",
"mocha": "^3.2.0"},
```

and importing the cryptojs as

```
import  CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
```

i am getting the following error

Plugin Error
Fetch error: 404 Not Found Instantiating http://localhost:3000/public/crypto-js Loading http://localhost:3000/public/plugins/xxxx-simple-json-datasource/datasource.js Loading plugins/xxxx-simple-json-datasource/module

Answer (score 0):

CryptoJS is a package, use its function according to requirements.

Try

```
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(myString, myPassword);
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, myPassword);
decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```